# Django Documentation part 4 <Forms and generic views> return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,))) Not working

Tags: python, django

This is Working 
[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQEHd.png)

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})
        # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

But when I use  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,))) .. Not Working
[Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S248G.png)

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        #return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

It shows

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/3/vote/
```

Reverse for 'results' not found. 'results' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/3/vote/
Django Version: 3.0.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'results' not found. 'results' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Users\shaff\Anaconda3\envs\First_Django_App\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677
Python Executable:  C:\Users\shaff\Anaconda3\envs\First_Django_App\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.7
Python Path:
['G:\Django_Project\First_Django_App',
 'C:\Users\shaff\Anaconda3\envs\First_Django_App\python37.zip',
 'C:\Users\shaff\Anaconda3\envs\First_Django_App\DLLs',
 'C:\Users\shaff\Anaconda3\envs\First_Django_App\lib',
 'C:\Users\shaff\Anaconda3\envs\First_Django_App',
 'C:\Users\shaff\Anaconda3\envs\First_Django_App\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 22 Apr 2020 07:54:46 +0000``

Full Code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Choice, Question

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request,'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        #return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

Comment: files urls.py are more relevant to see where is the problem.

Comment: thank you ... I found my fault in urls.py.